# Big-O notation prove

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to prove that this formula *(n<sup>2</sup>+1)/(n+1)* is *O(n)*

As you know, we need to come up with *n0* and *C*.

So I'm confused a little bit about how to choose an appropriate *C* since the equation here is division.

So with *C=1*,  *(n<sup>2</sup>+1) / (n+1) / n*

*(n<sup>2</sup>+n) / (n+n) / n* >= *(n<sup>2</sup>+1) /(n+1)*

but I'm stuck here in how to simplify the division here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As n tends to infinity your original equation becomes n^2/n  which is equivalent to O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Choosing `c = 1`:

```
(n^2 + 1)/(n + 1) <= 1*n        definition of Big-Oh with c = 1
n^2 + 1 <= n^2 + n              multiplying both sides by n + 1
1 <= n                          subtracting n^2 from both sides
n >= 1                          rearranging
```

Therefore, the choice `n0 = 1` works for `c = 1`.